# Complex grep awk command needed

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

I have loge file have alot of lines, the below line is sample for it
I have 2 keys. First Key is sub. Id (1112222222) second key is session id (xxx.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034).

sub Id is know, i need to create a big shell command to search for the session id of this sub id and then search in the file for all lines which have one of those keys or both of them. For example below line contains both session id and sub id pair.

```
úú 3 [ +548] EPC_Log: bi_tspSequenceId=1; i_tspSeverity=6;  vc_MessageInformation=CCR received. SessionId: xxx.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034, SubsId: 1112222222, IpAddr: 1.1.1.1, Protocol: Gx, RequestType: Create, APN: apn.com, Event-Trigger: ;i_Priority=6úúûû TelORB: Tue Aug 11 12:26:05 2015,  Host:úú Tue Aug 11 12:26:18 2015
```

**Input Ex.**

```
úú 3 [ +548] EPC_Log: bi_tspSequenceId=1; i_tspSeverity=6;  vc_MessageInformation=CCR received. SessionId: xxx.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034, SubsId: 1112222222, IpAddr: 1.1.1.1, Protocol: Gx, RequestType: Create, APN: apn.com, Event-Trigger: ;i_Priority=6úúûû TelORB: Tue Aug 11 12:26:05 2015,  Host:úú Tue Aug 11 12:26:18 2015
úú 3 [ +548] EPC_Log: bi_tspSequenceId=1; i_tspSeverity=6;  vc_MessageInformation=CCA received. SessionId: xxx.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034, SubsId: 1112222222, IpAddr: 1.1.1.1, Protocol: Gx, RequestType: Create, APN: apn.com, Event-Trigger: ;i_Priority=6úúûû TelORB: Tue Aug 11 12:26:05 2015,  Host:úú Tue Aug 11 12:26:18 2015
úú 3 [ +548] EPC_Log: bi_tspSequenceId=1; i_tspSeverity=6;  vc_MessageInformation=CCR received. SessionId: yyy.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034, SubsId: 1113333333, IpAddr: 1.1.1.1, Protocol: Gx, RequestType: Create, APN: apn.com, Event-Trigger: ;i_Priority=6úúûû TelORB: Tue Aug 11 12:26:05 2015,  Host:úú Tue Aug 11 12:26:18 2015
úú 3 [ +548] EPC_Log: bi_tspSequenceId=1; i_tspSeverity=6;  vc_MessageInformation=CCA received. SessionId: yyy.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034, SubsId: 1112222222, IpAddr: 1.1.1.1, Protocol: Gx, RequestType: Create, APN: apn.com, Event-Trigger: ;i_Priority=6úúûû TelORB: Tue Aug 11 12:26:05 2015,  Host:úú Tue Aug 11 12:26:18 2015
```

**Output Ex.**

```
úú 3 [ +548] EPC_Log: bi_tspSequenceId=1; i_tspSeverity=6;  vc_MessageInformation=CCR received. SessionId: xxx.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034, SubsId: 1112222222, IpAddr: 1.1.1.1, Protocol: Gx, RequestType: Create, APN: apn.com, Event-Trigger: ;i_Priority=6úúûû TelORB: Tue Aug 11 12:26:05 2015,  Host:úú Tue Aug 11 12:26:18 2015
úú 3 [ +548] EPC_Log: bi_tspSequenceId=1; i_tspSeverity=6;  vc_MessageInformation=CCA received. SessionId: xxx.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034, SubsId: 1112222222, IpAddr: 1.1.1.1, Protocol: Gx, RequestType: Create, APN: apn.com, Event-Trigger: ;i_Priority=6úúûû TelORB: Tue Aug 11 12:26:05 2015,  Host:úú Tue Aug 11 12:26:18 2015
úú 3 [ +548] EPC_Log: bi_tspSequenceId=1; i_tspSeverity=6;  vc_MessageInformation=CCA received. SessionId: yyy.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034, SubsId: 1112222222, IpAddr: 1.1.1.1, Protocol: Gx, RequestType: Create, APN: apn.com, Event-Trigger: ;i_Priority=6úúûû TelORB: Tue Aug 11 12:26:05 2015,  Host:úú Tue Aug 11 12:26:18 2015
```

Comment: please provide sample input data and corresponding output for that

Comment: You can check it in the body after update it with samples

Answer (score 0):

Untested

To extract the session id given a subs id:

```
subsId=1112222222
sessionIds=$( grep -oP 'SessionId: [^,]+,( SubsId: $subsId,)' file.log | sort -u)
```

Then to extract the lines with one of those session ids:

```
echo "$sessionIds" | grep -Ff- file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you SAY you want but it won't reproduce the posted expected output since that doesn't reflect what you say you want`*`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { subsid = subsid"," }
NR==FNR { if ($13 == subsid) sessids[$11]; next }
($11 in sessids) || ($13 == subsid)

$ awk -v subsid=1112222222 -f tst.awk file file
úú 3 [ +548] EPC_Log: bi_tspSequenceId=1; i_tspSeverity=6;  vc_MessageInformation=CCR received. SessionId: xxx.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034, SubsId: 1112222222, IpAddr: 1.1.1.1, Protocol: Gx, RequestType: Create, APN: apn.com, Event-Trigger: ;i_Priority=6úúûû TelORB: Tue Aug 11 12:26:05 2015,  Host:úú Tue Aug 11 12:26:18 2015
úú 3 [ +548] EPC_Log: bi_tspSequenceId=1; i_tspSeverity=6;  vc_MessageInformation=CCA received. SessionId: xxx.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034, SubsId: 1112222222, IpAddr: 1.1.1.1, Protocol: Gx, RequestType: Create, APN: apn.com, Event-Trigger: ;i_Priority=6úúûû TelORB: Tue Aug 11 12:26:05 2015,  Host:úú Tue Aug 11 12:26:18 2015
úú 3 [ +548] EPC_Log: bi_tspSequenceId=1; i_tspSeverity=6;  vc_MessageInformation=CCR received. SessionId: yyy.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034, SubsId: 1113333333, IpAddr: 1.1.1.1, Protocol: Gx, RequestType: Create, APN: apn.com, Event-Trigger: ;i_Priority=6úúûû TelORB: Tue Aug 11 12:26:05 2015,  Host:úú Tue Aug 11 12:26:18 2015
úú 3 [ +548] EPC_Log: bi_tspSequenceId=1; i_tspSeverity=6;  vc_MessageInformation=CCA received. SessionId: yyy.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034, SubsId: 1112222222, IpAddr: 1.1.1.1, Protocol: Gx, RequestType: Create, APN: apn.com, Event-Trigger: ;i_Priority=6úúûû TelORB: Tue Aug 11 12:26:05 2015,  Host:úú Tue Aug 11 12:26:18 2015
```

`*` Why aren't all 4 input lines expected in the output you show in your question?

Your target SubsId `1112222222` is associated with SessionId `xxx.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034` at lines 1 and 2 and with SessionId `yyy.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034` at line 4.

You say you want to output `all lines which have one of those keys or both of them`. Like line 4, line 3 has SessionId `yyy.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034`.

So lines 1,2, and 4 should be printed due to matching SubsId `1112222222` and line 3 should be printed for matching SessionId `yyy.apn.com;2418561818;846;60034` since SubsId `1112222222` is associated with that SessionId at line 4.

Right?

Comment: Thanks for your help first. Line 3 should not be matched beacause sessionID yyy is not same as sessionID xxx. I am filtering over line which have sub. ID 11122222222 and its session ID which is xxx

But session ID yyy is related to sub ID 11133333333

Comment: But sub. ID 11122222222  is associated with session ID yyy at line `SessionId: yyy... SubsId: 1112222222`. How are you deciding that Subsid 1112222222 should only be associated with `xxx` and not `yyy` for the purposes of selecting lines to output?

Comment: you are right. consider last one is different sub id